# Where to place the unlink code to delete a file from the server

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript function below where it removes an appended file name from .listImage when the user clicks on the "Delete" button:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage">Delete</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }


      $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {

        $(this).parent().remove();

    });

      return true;   
}
```

As you can see the `$(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {` is used to delete the correct appended file name.

But what I want to do is that when the user deletes a file name, it also deletes the file from the server. So I am trying to use this code:  `unlink($_FILES["fileImage"]["temp_name"]);` to delete the file from the server.

But what I want to know is that where do I store this code so that it uses the javascript function to delete the appended file name but then be able to go onto the php script to delete the file from the server?

BELOW IS the php script (imageupload.php) where the uploading of files occur:

```
<?php

session_start();

$result = 0;

if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
    $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
    $ext = array_pop($parts);
    $base = implode(".",$parts);
    $n = 2;

    while( file_exists("ImageFiles2/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
    $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
    "ImageFiles2/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
    $result = 1;

}
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles2/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

      }

?>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use an `ajax` call to your php script to allow deletion of files on the server. JQuery's `ajax` documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

First, you will need to connect your button and image file name like so

```
$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Delete</button><br/><hr/></div>');
```

Now, your delete method will then look something like this.

```
$(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {
    // Find the image file name that is associated with this delete button. You 
    // may want to think about linking the image file name and the delete button
    // in a better way than this.
    var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    console.log("Deleting " + image_file_name);
    jQuery.ajax("delete.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
      .done(function(data) {
        $(".msg").append(data);
       });
});
```

Finally, the `delete.php` will need to look something like this

```
<?php
  $image_file_name = "ImageFiles/" . $_GET["imagefilename"];
  if (User Uploaded this File || Has Permission to Delete it)
  {
    print "Deleting $image_file_name";
    // This assumes delete.php is in the same directory as the image file.
    unlink($image_file_name);
  }
?>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/hEEeP/1/) to show you working code.

Comment: OK, just to make sure before I mark this answer, in the delete.php page, do I only need to store in the `unlink($_FILES["fileImage"]["temp_name"]);` in that page to delete the file or do I need to include additional code for deletion?

Comment: Also where you stated filename, did you mean imagefilename?

Comment: Ok thanks for the code but problem is that it is not deleting the file from the server. When using JQuery.ajax do I need to download some jquery files to use this? Or is there something wrong with the code? I will update code above

Comment: **AAAAAAA!** Don't just unlink any file that the user tells you! Remember that `delete.php` may be called by anyone with any parameters -- validate that the file specified was uploaded by the user first.

Comment: @duskwuff It is ok I do have validation on which files can go and not go into the server. Also the user can only delete the files they have uploaded, not what anyone else has uploaded. By the way does unlink actually remove a file from the server or doesn't it? I thought unlink does do this but not 100% sure?

Comment: @duskwuff Fair point. I updated the example to be more clear for new users.

Comment: But it is still not deleting it from the server, When I click on delete button, it removes the appended file name but in the server it does not remove the file itself. i updated code in question

Comment: @user1359453 Try adding some print statements to see what is going wrong. I added some to my example script to show how. I also added a `done` function handler for the `ajax` call.

Comment: @BrantOlsen When doing `print "Deleting $image_file_name";`, it is stating that $image_file_name is 'undefined'.

Comment: @user1359453 Could be that `attr('src')` is not the correct value to use. I added a `console.log` command before the ajax call. Try that to  what is being passed to `delete.php`.

Comment: This is the message it is displaying in the firebug when using console.log: Deleting undefined

`QandATable.php (line 790)
GET https://helios.hud.ac.uk/..../deleteimage.php?imagefilename=undefined`

Comment: @user1359453 Which tag is `.deletefileimage` on and what does your html for that section look like? Please just add this to your question.

Comment: the tag .deletefileimage is the class given to the delete button. It is  shown in the code, look at this line in the code: `$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage">Delete</button><br/><hr/></div>');`

Comment: @user1359453 I see. The issue is then that the file's name is not found within the `deletefileimage` button. I updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: @BrantOlsen Good effort but it is still stating that image_file_name is undefined :(

Comment: @user1359453 Can you show the html that is displayed on the webpage? This way I can see the exact parent-child relationship.

Comment: It is finding the file name when displaying the message "Deleting Tuplips.png" for example, but the final problem is that after clicking on delete for a file name, it is not deleting the file from the server. The file is still in the server when it should be removed. If you can figure this out then you have solved the whole problem :) I have upvoted your answer as well because you are really tackling this problem quite well :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10756/discussion-between-brant-olsen-and-user1359453)

Answer (score 1):

Good idea to store your uploaded files in public temp directory and move then only when content saved.

Another way to have list of all all the time uploaded files with marker "active/inactive" and periodicly run script that deletes old files (inactive and created hours or days ago). In this case when you adding files or deleting content you mark it as "inactive", and when you save content you mark used files as "active".

Comment: btw you always can use javascript implementation as http://stackoverflow.com/a/10399888/765634 but know what happened when you close browser page